# How to save a stream on google drive?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

My application running on google app engine, so can not use File. I want to save a pdf file on other site to google drive, but get a IllegalArgumentException

```
file.setMimeType("application/pdf");
mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(file.getMimeType(),
                   url.openStream());

try {
    File result = getDrive().files().insert(file, mediaContent)
                .execute();
        return result.getId();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Fixed by save pdf bytes to a File instance

Answer (score 0):

Check the Google Drive SDK documentation for a complete Java sample application running on App Engine showing how to read and save files to Drive:

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java